# Is there any benefit of using @Async on service methods when the controller blocks on the returned future in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Sorry if this has been asked before, I've searched and couldn't find a clear answer.

Essentially, what I'm asking is if there is any point to have the following:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
   ...
   @Get("/blah")
   public List<String> getBlah() {
      try {
      return testService.getBlah().get();
      } catch (...) {
        ...
      }
   }
}

@Service
public class TestService {

   @Async
   public CompletableFuture<List<String>> getBlah() {
      final var retList = new ArrayList<String>();
      // do some work here
      return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(retList);
   }
}
```

I do understand the benefit of doing multiple async calls in the controller then gathering multiple futures before returning, but in the case where there is a single async call that the controller will block on to get the result is there any point of using async or should I just let the call happen on the controller thread?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I see no benefits. Better to let the call happen on the controller thread instead. That way you also don't have to reconfigure eg spring security with `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` in order to access the SecurityContext from the spawned thread

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Well I do have other controllers where @Async is needed so I'm guessing that doesn't apply.